# Disappearing Butler in The Sexy Brutale

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

In the Sexy Brutale, at about 4, I followed a butler in a corridor below the surveillance room.

The corridor ends in a room, with no other exit than the corridor I'm in.

The butler walks in, and then just, disappear. The sound says it walks to a corner and then, he's gone. The door is a special one, I can't spy through it; There's no way to hide in the room.

So where is that butler going?

Comment: Any answer to this question is inherently a spoiler. Keep playing the game

Comment: Ok, I'll ignore any answers if I get any until I finish the game. Thanks for the Spoiler Warning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is considered a spoiler as I realized it through observation fairly early on.

Every time you notice one of the casino staff (the "butlers") vanish, it's in a room that has no keyhole.  All of these rooms also contain a mirror.

> Late in the game, you find out that there's an area accessed through the mirrors. The casino staff go there after they commit the murders they're responsible for.

Comment: Yeah I think that butler goes there right after giving the red shot on the roulette.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning you get the ability to travel through the mirrors yourself after acquiring Eleanor’s mask